# Hypen issue in urls in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a simple action in my Controller:

```
public function actionReset( $key ) {
    echo $key;
    Yii::$app->end();
}
```

I am allowing this in my behaviors:

```
'rules'      => [
    [
        'actions' => [ 'message', 'activate', 'reset-request', 'reset' ],
        'allow'   => true,
    ],
],
```

it works fine. However as soon as I change the action to `actionResetPassword` and allow `reset-password` I get a 404 error. The funny thing is is that if I go to the url without the key in the address so:

`/action/reset-password` I get a 400 error that `$key` is missing.

but going to `action/reset-password/somekeyhere` I get 404 not found error.

EDIT:

This has to do with the hyphen in the action name:

--

WORKS:

rule: `reset-password`

action: `actionResetpassword($key)`

url tested: `~/action/resetpassword/somekeyhere`

--

DOESN'T WORK:

rule: `reset-password`

action: `actionResetPassword($key)`

url tested: `~/action/reset-password/somekeyhere`

--

DOESN'T WORK:

rule: `reset-password`

action: `actionResetpassword($key)`

url tested: `~/action/reset-password/somekeyhere`

--

WORKS:

rule: `reset-password`

action: `actionResetPassword()`

url tested: `~/action/resetpassword`

--

Comment: try this `action/reset-password?key=somekeyvalue`

Comment: Did you mean `reset-password` in the rules? Or `reset-request`?

Comment: i change the rule to say `reset-password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out

The issue was in the config of urlManager

Needed to fix the RegEx from:

`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`

To:

`'<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`

Answer (score 2):

[No there isn't.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#action-ids) There's some character limitation though but that's it. Whatever the issue cannot be that.